# Load and Execute XAML with reference to in-project Activity

Tags: xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I made an Activity Library project. Next, I created a few Workflows in the project, mostly as demonstrations of Input and Output arguments. I see those as reusable components (Activities) in the toolbox, and have used several in some FlowChart Activities. This works fine in a compiled manner. However, when loading and executing the Workflow from XAML, it fails when it comes to the reference to the Activity from within my project.

What needs to be done in order to re-use Activities from the same project when loading and executing Workflows from XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your problem lies in the fact that when you create activities the xmlns:local propery doesn't include the assembly name, only the namespace name. This means that when you load a XAML file, the runtime assumes that the namespace is found in the currently executing assembly. This is an incorrect assumption when you are referencing an activity library from an application.

You have two options to fix the problem.

1) You can manually append "**;assembly=MyActivityLibrary**" to the xmlns:local property (at the top of you XAML file). This is simple to do but if you ever modify the XAML in Visual Studio then you will have to remember to redo your change every time.

2) When you call XamlServices.Load you can pass a second parameter of type XamlXmlReaderSettings and specify the LocalAssembly property to be your activity library assembly. This would be the more stable approach to take. Then no manual editing of the XAML file is required when you

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now. Are you explaining that in order to reference custom activities, they must be contained within an assembly, even if loading and compiling XAML on the fly? We were hoping to avoid deployment of anything but the out-of-the-box assemblies. It sounds like we need to put our custom activities in an assembly at a minimum, and that will need to be available in the current process when the XAML is loaded and compiled. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Before I answer that definitively, let me make sure I understand your scenario.  You have some custom activities that you _want_ to store in uncompiled XAML.  You also have some workflows that you want to store in uncompiled XAML.  You want to be able to load/compile the custom workflows (that in turn reference the  custom activities)  at run time without requiring any assemblies outside of the standard WF ones.  Is this all correct?

Comment: Looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) it doesn't seem like you can reference another XAML file within an xmlns of a XAML file. Given that, I think your direction in the top comment is going to be the best bet. There *might* be a way to utilize the [TypeResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx) event to dynamically load the activities but _if_ it is even possible it would certainly take some time and effort to figure out.